# How to avoid msbuild publishing referenced project?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution (called Twins) with 3 projects:

1. Class Library (Lib)
2. WCF Service Application (WCF)
3. ASP .NET MVC Application (Site)

References

- Site references WCF and Lib.
- WCF references Lib.

I am trying to build and **publish** (WebPublishMethod = FileSystem) Site and WCF from the command line using msbuild.

This works for WCF project (split over multiple lines for clarity):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe 
.\Twins.sln /t:Wcf
/p:"VisualStudioVersion=12.0;PublishProfile=wcfprofile;DeployOnBuild=true"
```

This fails for Site project:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
.\Twins.sln /t:Site
/p:"VisualStudioVersion=12.0;PublishProfile=siteprofile;DeployOnBuild=true"
```

Short error message

```
The value for PublishProfile is set to 'siteprofile', 
expected to find the file at
\Twins\Wcf\Properties\PublishProfiles\siteprofile.pubxml'
but it could not be found.
```

Detailed error message

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4331,5):
error : 
The value for PublishProfile is set to 'siteprofile', 
expected to find the file at 
'C:\Users\USERNAME\code\Twins\Wcf\Properties\PublishProfiles\siteprofile.pubxml'
but it could not be found.
[C:\Users\USERNAME\code\Twins\Wcf\Wcf.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4338,4):
error : 
PublishProfile(siteprofile) is set. 
But the $(WebPublishMethod) does not have a valid value. 
Current Value is "".
[C:\Users\USERNAME\code\Twins\Wcf\Wcf.csproj]
```

In Visual Studio I can right click on Site, select publish, select the sitepublish profile and only the site is published.

How do I build and publish the Site project from the command line just like I can do from inside Visual Studio? (Whether or not the WCF project is also built/published is not important.)